# Errors after importing Obj-C files through bridging header

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header, 360-panorama-viewer

I am trying to import [this](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama) project into my swift project. What I have done is add the `PanoromaView.h` and `PanoromaView.m` files, and added `#import "PanoramaView.h"` to my bridging header. I have also added the OpenGLES.framework and GLKit.Framework to my project.

I am now getting errors saying

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'GLKView', superclass of
>   'PanoramaView'

and

> Unknown type name 'GLKVector3'

This is an image of the errors in the code:

[image]

If anybody can help explain what these are how I remove them that would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have also tried installing through Cocoapods and still get the exact same errors, very strange?

Comment: You need to import whatever `PanoramaView` depends on.  You should double check the source of those files and follow very closely the installation guidelines.

Comment: There are no installation guidelines, as you can see on the link. So I'm trying to work it out myself and I am stuck at this point. I thought I had importing everything it depends on I'm not sure what else is needed?

Comment: Oh, well... it's a pod.  Just use CocoaPods to install it?  `pod 'PanoramaView'`

Comment: I have never used pods before but I will give this a try also then. Thanks

Comment: @nhgrif I have now installed with CocoaPods but still get the exact same errors? Can you assist any further?

Comment: Try to not use Parse. It's about to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make it work, I had to add this into `PanoramaView.h`:

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
```

Suggested on the github code does not work for me from the box. Also I had to modify ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: GLKViewController {

    var panoramaView = PanoramaView()

    override func loadView() {
        panoramaView.setImageWithName("park_2048.jpg")
        panoramaView.touchToPan = true          // Use touch input to pan
        panoramaView.orientToDevice = false     // Use motion sensors to pan
        panoramaView.pinchToZoom = true         // Use pinch gesture to zoom
        panoramaView.showTouches = true         // Show touches
        self.view = panoramaView
    }

    override func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
        panoramaView.draw()
    }
}
```

This is my sample app:

https://github.com/melifaro-/Swift-PanoramaSample

Hope it helps.

BTW, I did not use CocoaPods. I use `PanoramaView.h` and `PanoramaView.m` files only.

Comment: Thank you this is brilliant, just what I needed. I am not sure if you could also help me partially further. I want to be able to load the panoroma inside a view rather then a viewController? I know I have to use the GLKView but do you have any example code on this also would be great. thanks again

Comment: Yep, sure. That won't be difficult.

Comment: Thank you, where will I find this?

Comment: That shouldn't, but that is. I had to modify PanoramaView class itself. You can check out my sample on github. I have pushed changes there.

Comment: This isn't inside a GLKView, this is inside a GLKViewController?

Comment: Oh Sorry I see what you have done now, Thanks for this - although I meant done programmatically, I do not like to use the IB... If you know how to do with just the code that would be great.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Ok thanks for your help then. What you have created is a GLKViewController in the IB. Do you know how to add a GLKView through the IB rather then through code then?

Comment: If my understanding is corrent you need both for correct work. Actually in the latest version there are presented both GLKViewController and GLKView (PanoramaView) in the storyboard file.

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to do is change the GLKViews frame size, what you have provided the view is embedded in the VC and the dimensions cannot be changed?

Comment: Right, It occupies all the available space. Not sure how to change the GLKView frame size.